# where to place htaccess file for php MVC

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I'm building a php MVC application from scratch, that is I'm building my own framework as a part of a project. I read tutorials and it says that i have to modify the htaccess file and include it in the application root.

My project is inside htdocs of xammp i have it like this so far

```
htdocs
     MvcApplication
```

I will include the corresponding directories suchas Controllers, Views etc. What I don't understand is where do i include the htaccess that will apply only to THIS specific project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the .htaccess file goes right inside the htdocs folder.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: It will not go inside my project folder? Like htdocs/project/.htaccess

Comment: If that is how you have it set up then yes. .htaccess files will affect the directory it's in and every subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

In the root directory of your project.

So if http://localhost/index.php maps to c:\project\index.php, put it in c:\project.